# Not understanding behavior of MobX-utils fromResource

Tags: mobx, mobx-utils

This is a modified version of the [`now()`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils/blob/master/src/now.ts) implementation from [mobx-utils](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils). From my understanding, when the `autorun` function is triggered, "initial" would be logged, then after 1 second, the value of `Date.now()`, then `Date.now()` again and again every second.

```
function createIntervalTicker(interval) {
    let subscriptionHandle
    return fromResource(
        sink => {
            subscriptionHandle = setInterval(
                () => sink(Date.now()),
                interval
            );
        },
        () => {
            clearInterval(subscriptionHandle);
        },
        'initial'
    );
}

autorun(() => {
  console.log(createIntervalTicker(1000).current())
})
```

However, I am getting "initial" logged out every second again and again. The value of `Date.now()` is never logged.

It seems that when `sink(Date.now())` is called, it is only triggering the the autorun function, but not updating the value returned by `current()`.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

`mobx@3.1.16`
`mobx-utils@2.0.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a new observable and passes its value to `console.log` each time `autorun` is executed. Hence, you always see `initial` in the browser console: mobx tracks changes to the initial observable, but `console.log` receives new observable on each reaction.

Solution: store a reference to the initial observable and reuse it

```
const ticker = createIntervalTicker(1000);
autorun(() => {
  console.log(ticker.current())
})
```

Comment: D'oh that seems so obvious now. Thank you.